# GradientBrush in WPF

Tags: wpf, colors, gradient

I want to give color to a path but not linearly, for example if I have a path in the shape of 'S' . I want to give a color to path such that it starts from top point gradually increase the color to given color from white till the end point. I cant do this linearly.Is there any kind of brush which I can use.

Comment: A picture of what you "intend" can really help us understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Have a look at what Charles Petzold did.](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/02/Graphical-Paths-with-Gradient-Colors.html)